# Remove TerminalServices SSLCertificateSHA1Hash

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop, certificate, wmic

I would like to remove RDP certificate that I previously set through the command

`wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\TerminalServices PATH Win32_TSGeneralSetting Set SSLCertificateSHA1Hash=$CertificateThumbprint`

Is it safe to direct remove the certificate or exists some command like

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\TerminalServices PATH Win32_TSGeneralSetting Remove SSLCertificateSHA1Hash
```

that I need to run before delete the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide another certificate to replace this one.

Do not delete the certificate that you defined as the RDP Certificate, otherwise you might be unable to connect again via RDP.